# Equation numbering in systeme package

Tags: equations, numbering, systeme

I've produced the following code using the `systeme` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{systeme}

\begin{document}

\[
\systeme{3x+y+2z=6,x+3y+2z=-6,x+y+z=1}
\]

\end{document}
```

This displays the equations as I would expect, apart from the fact that I'd like to add equation numbers to each of the three equations such that the numbering is in-keeping with the equation numbering in the rest of the document.

The equation numbers should appear on the right-hand side immediately after each equation.

Is this possible?

Comment: Where should the equation numbers be placed. More or less immediately to the right of the system, at the right-hand margin of the text block, or somewhere else? Please advise.

Comment: @Mico I've made an edit to include this information :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For automatic equation numbering, with the equation numbers -- surrounded by parentheses -- placed to the right of the equations, it suffices to insert `@(*)` immediately after the *first* equation. If you require more separation -- say, `\qquad` -- you could insert `@\qquad(*)` instead.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,systeme}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
\systeme{3x+y+2z=6,x+3y+2z=-6,x+y+z=1} \\[2ex]        % no numbering
\systeme{3x+y+2z=6@(*), x+3y+2z=-6, x+y+z=1} \\[2ex]  % default separation
\systeme{3x+y+2z=6@\qquad(*), x+3y+2z=-6, x+y+z=1}    % separation by '\qquad'
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

---

***Addendum***, to address the OP's follow-up question: To have the equation numbers produced by `\systeme` pick up the value of the `equation` counter, I suggest you insert the instructions

```
\renewcommand{\SYSeqnum}{\value{equation}}
\sysautonum{(**)}
```

in the preamble (*after* loading the `systeme` package) and omit the `@(*)` directives mentioned above. I.e., something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{systeme}
\renewcommand{\SYSeqnum}{\value{equation}}
\sysautonum{(**)}

\begin{document}
\addtocounter{equation}{5}\theequation
\[
\systeme{3x+y+2z=6, x+3y+2z=-6 , x+y+z=1 }
\]

\stepcounter{equation}\theequation
\[
\systeme{3x+y+2z=6  , 
         x+3y+2z=-6 , 
         x+y+z=1    }
\]
\theequation
\end{document}
```

With this setup, the first three `systeme` equations will  be numbered 6, 7, and 8, and the next three `systeme` equations will be number 10, 11, and 12.

---

Or, take the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,systeme}
\renewcommand{\SYSeqnum}{\value{equation}}
\sysautonum{(**)}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather} % create 7 dummy numbered equations:
a \\ b \\ c \\ d \\ e \\ f \\ g 
\end{gather}
\[
\systeme{3x+y+2z=6, x+3y+2z=-6 , x+y+z=1 }
\]
\end{document}
```

With this setup, the three `systeme` equations will be numbered 8, 9, and 10.

---

***Second addendum***, to address the topic of how to create cross-references to equations within a `systeme` system (pun intended). It's important to note that the standard `\label`-`\ref` mechanism doesn't work for such equations. The following MWE is based on the description of the `systeme`'s approach, on p. 7 of the package's user guide.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{systeme}
\renewcommand{\SYSeqnum}{\value{equation}} 
\sysautonum{(**)}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{equation}{15}
\systeme{3x+y+2z=6 @\gdef\foo{**}(**),  % see p. 7 of the package's user guide
         x+3y+2z=-6@\gdef\bar{**}(**), 
         x+y+z=1   @\gdef\baz{**}(**)}      

Cross-references to equations (\foo) and (\baz).
\end{document}
```

This MWE outputs "Cross-references to equations (16) and (18)."

Comment: Is it possible to force the equation numbers to pick up the counter from previous equation numbering? That is, if I have, for example, an ```align``` environment beforehand whose numbering finished at (7), can we force the ```systeme``` numbers to pick up from (8)?

Comment: @MHW - Please see the addendum I just posted.

Comment: @MHW - I've posted a second addendum to explain how `systeme`' cross-referencing mechanism works.

Comment: The addendums are greatly appreciated. This now covers everything I needed.

Comment: @minhthien_2016 - The easiest and best way to suppress equation numbering is to use `equation*`, `align*`, `gather*`, etc environments instead of `equation`, `align`, `gather`, etc environments.

Comment: @minhthien_2016 - Sorry for any misunderstandings. You wrote, "I want to stop number equations"; I think my follow-up posting answers that question.

Answer (score 3):

If it is possible to have numbers for the system equations not to be placed at the right margin, here is a simple solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{systeme}
\usepackage{linegoal} 

\begin{document}

\setcounter{equation}{10}

\[ \sysautonum*{\stepcounter{equation}\hbox{(\theequation)}}
\systeme{3x+y+2z=6,x+3y+2z=-6,x+y+z=1} \]%

\[ \sysautonum*{\stepcounter{equation}\hbox{(\theequation)}}
\systeme{3x+y+2z=6,x+3y+2z=-6,x+y+z=1} \]

\begin{equation}
  a + c = b +d
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to individually label and reference each equation? When I try to label within the ```\systeme``` command and later reference those labels, it simply produces alphabetic references (e.g. (a)) instead of the actual equation numbers.

Comment: I don't know, as I never tried that. I'll try to look at the code tomorrow(it's getting very late here) and see what can be done.

Comment: @MHW - Please check out the material at the top of page 7 of the package's user guide for an example of how to cross-reference equations created with `systeme`. Hint: you can't the standard `\label`-`\ref` LaTeX mechanism.