# How can I turn on and turn off numbering equations with systeme?

Tags: systeme

I see [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/583380/equation-numbering-in-systeme-package)

I don't want to number all equations of my document. How can I do it?

```
 \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage{systeme}
    \renewcommand{\SYSeqnum}{\value{equation}}
    \sysautonum{(**)}
    \begin{document}
    \renewcommand{\SYSeqnum}{\value{equation}} 
    \sysautonum{(**)}
    \setcounter{equation}{2}
    \[ \systeme{x + 2 y - 3 z  -4 = 0 @\gdef\foo{**}(**), 
        x  - 2 y + 4 z  -3=0@\gdef\bar{**}(**), 
        3 x - 5 y - z  +2 = 0   @\gdef\baz{**}(**)}  \]
    
    \[ \systeme{x + 2 y - 3 z  -4 = 0 @\gdef\foo{**}(**), 
        4 y -7 z  -1=0@\gdef\bar{**}(**), 
        11 y - 8z  -14 = 0   @\gdef\baz{**}(**)}     \]
    
    \[ \systeme{x + 2 y - 3 z  -4 = 0 @\gdef\foo{**}(**), 
        44 y -77 z  -11=0@\gdef\bar{**}(**), 
        44 y - 32z  -56 = 0   @\gdef\baz{**}(**)}  \]
        
    \[ \systeme{x + 2 y - 3 z  -4 = 0 @\gdef\foo{**}(**), 
        44 y -77 z  -11=0@\gdef\bar{**}(**), 
        - 45z  + 45 = 0   @\gdef\baz{**}(**)}    \]
    
    I \textit{don't want} to number the following equations 
    
    \[ \systeme{x + 2 y - 3 z  -4 = 0 @\gdef\foo{**}(**), 
        44 y -77 z  -11=0@\gdef\bar{**}(**), 
        - 45z  + 45 = 0   @\gdef\baz{**}(**)}    \]
        
        I  want to number the following equations 
        
        \[ \systeme{x + 2 y - 3 z  -4 = 0 @\gdef\foo{**}(**), 
            44 y -77 z  -11=0@\gdef\bar{**}(**), 
            - 45z  + 45 = 0   @\gdef\baz{**}(**)}    \]
            
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: First, remove `\sysautonum{(**)}` (every occurence).  In this MWE it isn't needed anyw;ay.  Second, remove `@{**}` on the lines you don't want numbered.  You might need to save and reset the equation counter.  Finally, you can remove every`\gdef\foo{**}` as it has no function AFAICT.